# PHP: XML parsing issues

Tags: php, xml

Im trying to create a payment system that integrates with eWay .. They have supplied some code for processing payments, except when i run it im getting the following error:

> Message: Undefined index: value
>
> Line Number: 106

The function that line 106 references is as follows:

```
    function parseResponse($xmlResponse){
    $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $xmlResponse, $xmlData, $index);
    $responseFields = array();
    foreach($xmlData as $xData)
        if($xData["level"] == 2)
            $responseFields[$xData["tag"]] = $xData["value"];
    return $responseFields;
    }
```

Im really stuck on this, i cant seem to get it working.

Any help on diagnosing this would be fantastic.

Cheers,

The XML im trying to parse is as follows

```
<ewaygateway>
<ewayCustomerID>87654321</ewayCustomerID>
<ewayTotalAmount>44000</ewayTotalAmount>
<ewayCardHoldersName>Testing Test</ewayCardHoldersName>
<ewayCardNumber>4444333322221111</ewayCardNumber>
<ewayCardExpiryMonth>04</ewayCardExpiryMonth>
<ewayCardExpiryYear>15</ewayCardExpiryYear>
<ewayCustomerFirstName>Testing test</ewayCustomerFirstName>
<ewayCustomerLastName>Testing test</ewayCustomerLastName>
<ewayCustomerEmail>info@emailaddress.com.au</ewayCustomerEmail>
<ewayCustomerAddress>123 Testing St</ewayCustomerAddress>
<ewayCustomerPostcode>2000</ewayCustomerPostcode>
<ewayCustomerInvoiceDescription>Membership</ewayCustomerInvoiceDescription>
<ewayCustomerInvoiceRef>00001</ewayCustomerInvoiceRef>
<ewayTrxnNumber>000001</ewayTrxnNumber>
<ewayOption1>Nice</ewayOption1>
<ewayOption2>Big</ewayOption2>
<ewayOption3>Option</ewayOption3>
</ewaygateway>
```

Also, this is how the xml is being generated

```
        $xmlRequest = "<ewaygateway><ewayCustomerID>" . $this->myCustomerID . "</ewayCustomerID>";
    foreach($this->myTransactionData as $key=>$value)
        $xmlRequest .= "<$key>$value</$key>";
    $xmlRequest .= "</ewaygateway>";
```

Comment: Any chance you could post the XML you're trying to parse?

Comment: I have added the XML, also the offending line is $responseFields[$xData["tag"]] = $xData["value"]; .... Also, if everything is perfect and the credit card is valid, no errors are returned .... but if a wrong credit card number is entered it brings up the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<ewaygateway>` tag has no value. Just check to make sure the value index exists with isset.

Comment: Reason: it's the root tag. Contained tags don't count as values.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response ... Im not sure what you mean, is there any chance you could show me an example of what i should try?

Comment: Bascially, I meant to change `$responseFields[$xData["tag"]] = $xData["value"];` to `$responseFields[$xData["tag"]] = isset($xData["value"]) ? $xData["value"] : null;`. Afterward, you can test to see if any of the values are null to find out if the user omitted some info without causing the notice to trigger.

Comment: Ohh, that has worked fantastic ... fixed all the errors ... Thank you so much!!!!!!!